# Audio playback of 8kHz and 44.1kHz on Android

Tags: android-audiomanager

Is it possible to play 8khz and 44.1kHz audio simultaneously in
 Android? If yes, how is this achieved? Is it using AlsaMixer or
 AudioFlinger (MixerThread) or does it need Audio HW codec support?

Thank you

---

let me put my question in this way:

I have a Mp3 file playing and there are some voice data which are played in between while I am listening to a song. So my question is, does these two files, mp3 and voice data are getting mixed using some mixer and then played over output device or they are just played individually? Does any one tell if a mixer(ALSA) is always needed while trying to play mp3 and voice note?

Comment: The `AudioFlinger` is not used directly by applications. You would use `MediaPlayer`, `AudioTrack`, `SoundPool` or `OpenSL ES`. As for whether you could have two players running at the same time at different sample rates; I don't see why not. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I cannot achieve simultaneous playback of 2 files.Only one file can be played while other is paused. So what is the role mixer thread in AudioFlinger and what is the role of ALSA mixer?